# How to handle highly correlated observations (rows)

Tags: autocorrelation, data-preprocessing, pruning

What is the best practice to handle highly similar/ autocorrelated observations (rows) in a data set. These highly similar rows could come from recording (some of the) observations at too close timestamps.
This is for example a problem also found in [pseudoreplication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreplication).

For highly correlated features (columns), one typically applied preprocessing step is dropping some of the columns which show high correlation or which have a high variance inflating factor (VIF).

How would one deal with very similar rows (which possibly have their origin in correlated observations) in the case of a classification task?

In the extreme case of duplicated rows some people drop the duplicated row.

One strategies for removing highly correlated observations could be to compute a n x n distance matrix between all n observations or do a clustering and drop observations which are too close

The question I have are:
a) is there literature related to this question?
b) would removing/subsampling rows with too high correlation improve generalization of the trained classifier? I would be happy if you could present an example or a counter example (or maybe both) in two dimensions for a binary classification.
c) how would an efficient implementation of dropping very similar rows look like in pandas?

PS: I found a related question here [Subsampling to account for spatial autocorrelation of observations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362725/subsampling-to-account-for-spatial-autocorrelation-of-observations) however it has no answers.

PPS: not randomly moving very similar samples from the training set into the test set is also important for a reliable validation (see pseudoreplication). As far as I know this is typically solved by some group base shuffling which requires however to define a feature based on which this grouping can happen.

Clarification about the type of date I am looking at:

1. Classification with repeated measurements $x_i$ at different times $i$ from one subject (e.g. measurements 1,2,3,4 come from subject 1, measurements 5,6,7,8,9 come from subject 2,...). Clearly, we have to avoid leakage and make a group split such that measurements from one subject only appear exclusively in the test or train split. However, having 4 strongly correlated measurements from subject 1 might not provide useful, one could aggregate some statistics about each subject, especially if the amount of measurements per subject is random. In this case, gathering the statistics would give equal weight to each subject. The situation becomes, however, more involved if, e.g., subject 1 and subject 2 themselves come from one region in sample space and they would have a small distance between them. Then they are correlated and gathering statistics over both could be beneficial. Is there any best practice which can be applied here? Any method, you would recommend?
2. Regression with autocorrelated time series. How would you go about it if the samples show high auto-correlation. Subsampling could be done, but is there more?

For both cases, could you please provide a verbose description of methods.

PPPS: this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.14486v1 suggests pruning observations depending on clustering for improved neural net training

Comment: Please provide more details about the nature of your data and the "classification task" you are undertaking. If you have individuals sampled at different times/frequencies and you are using logistic regression or a variant, it might be something as simple as a mixed model. I can't quite figure that out from your description, however. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: I do understand that the the answer might depend on the use case. I will try to point out two different scenarios in which I am interested.

Answer (score 2):

Markov processes, e.g., Markov logistic models, can handle even extremely high serial correlations all the way to absorbing states.  The cluster sandwich robust covariance matrix estimate can account for even complete redundancies in data such as truly duplicated observations (which are effectively ignored by the cluster sandwich approach).

Comment: Is [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250073603_The_sandwich_robust_covariance_matrix_estimator) what you are referring to, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of elaboration on Frank Harrell's answer (+1), in response to your addition to the question.

Throwing away data via subsampling is not generally a good idea. You want to use as much information as you have available. Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) is devoted to such issues in longitudinal measurements, but now goes beyond the original focus of that chapter of his [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) on generalized least squares for continuous outcomes.

For your second specific question, you can directly model autocorrelation where outcomes can change over a time series. You specify a function that combines time, prior outcome, and the time interval between measurements in a generalized linear model. Adapting an equation on page 7-39 of the current notes, where observation times $t$ are indexed by $i$, you can write a first-order Markov generalized linear model (GLM) as:

$$ g(Y(t_i)|X,Y(t_{i-1})) = \alpha + X\beta + f(Y(t_{i-1}), t_i, t_i - t_{i-1})$$

where $g()$ is the GLM link function, $Y$ is the outcome, $X$ is the set of covariates with coefficients $\beta$ to be estimated, $\alpha$ is an intercept, and the function $f()$

> involves any number of regression coefficients for a main effect of $t$, the main effect of time gap $t_i − t_{i−1}$ if this is not collinear with absolute time, a main effect of the previous state, and interactions between these.

If you want higher-order correlations, include more prior outcome observations and intervening gap times.

The illustration in the course notes is for a proportional odds ordinal logistic model; the principles apply in general. [This post](https://hbiostat.org/stat/irreg.html) shows how this can be done for binary outcomes at irregular observation times.

That also addresses part of the first specific question. Beyond that, the big problem with pseudoreplication is in estimating too narrow confidence intervals. One could argue that there's nothing wrong with giving a particular individual with more observations more weight, provided that you recognize those observations within the same individual aren't independent.

The "cluster sandwich robust covariance matrix estimate" starts with a model that assumes "working independence" and estimates the coefficients themselves as if all observations were independent. The covariance matrix is then adjusted for the clusters (subjects in your case). Random effects in mixed models, another standard way to handle multiple observations on subjects, also puts more weight on those with more observations.

Finally, unless you have tens of thousands of observations, your implied split into training and test sets is likely to [lose precision in the training and lose power in the testing](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/). Building the model on all the data and evaluating the modeling process by bootstrapping is superior. If you do have that many observations, simply splitting by subjects should be OK; you can check by doing repeated train/test splits.